# How should I implement Obj C-like headers in Lua?

Tags: objective-c, lua, header-files

Now I have an `import(a)` function, that in short words `dofile`'s header in `.framework` like this:
`import("<Kakao/KARect>") => dofile("/System/Library/Frameworks/Kakao.framework/Headers/KARect.lua")`

And in `KARect.lua` for example I have:

```
KARect = {}

function KARect:new(_x, _y, _width, _height, _colorBack)
    local new = setmetatable({}, {__index = self})

    new.id = KAEntities:generateID()
    ...

    return new
end

function KARect:draw()
    ...
end
```

---

After some time I thought about reworking this system and making "headers" work like typical Lua modules with advanced `require()` so function will do e.g.:

`import("<Kakao/KARect>") => package.path = "/System/Library/Frameworks/Kakao.framework/Headers/?.lua"; KARect = require("KARect")`

and file will contain:

```
local KARect = {}

...

return KARect
```

Because headers should *not* contain anything but only classes with their names? I'm getting confused when thinking about it, as I never used Obj C :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I never used Obj C

Then why are you trying to implement its headers in a language, that does not use headers at all?

### Header! What is a header?

Header files in C-like languages store more than just a name. They store constants and macro commands, function and class method argument and return types, structure and class fields. In essence, the contents of the header file are forward declarations. They came into existence due to the need to perform the same forward-declarations across many files.

I don't know what additional rules and functions were added to header files in Obj-C, but you can get general understanding of what they do in the following links: [1](https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_72.htm), [2](https://www.gribblelab.org/CBootCamp/12_Compiling_linking_Makefile_header_files.html), [3](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-header-file), [4](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/) with the last one being the most spot-on.

### Answer to the question present

Lua is dynamically-typed interpreted language. It does not do compile time type checks and, typically, Lua programs can and should be structured in a way that does not need forward declarations across files. So there is no meaningful way for a programmer to create and for lua bytecode generator and interpreter to use header files.

Lua [does not have classes](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) at all. The code you've posted is a syntactic sugar for an assignment of a function with a slightly different signature to a table which imitates class:

```
KARect.new = function( first_arg_is_self, _x, _y, _width, _height, _colorBack)
    local new = setmetatable({}, {__index = first_arg_is_self})
    return new
end
```

There is no declarations here, only generation of an anonymous function and its assignment to a field in a table. Other parts of program do not need to know anything about a particular field, variable or function (which is stored in variable) in advance (unlike C).

So, no declaration means nothing to separate from implementation. You of course can first list fields of the class-table and do dummy assignments to them, but, again, Lua will have no use for those. If you want to give hints to humans, it is probably better to write a dedicated manual or put comments in the implementation.

Lua has [situations](https://www.lua.org/pil/6.2.html) where forward declarations are needed to reference local functions. But this situation does not arise in object oriented code, as all methods are accessed through reference to the object, and by the time first object is created, the class itself is usually fully constructed.

Comment: Please say me the one thing: can headers **by their logic** contain more than just one class? I will flag this as accepted answer then.

Comment: Who are **they**? Lua does not have headers, C++ header can contain the program itself, dozen classes and whole ANSI specification text in a middle of that (but good ones do not). Because in C++ .hpp file is just a way to inform the compiler about what functions, objects and variables it would get if it had processed the (typically) corresponding .cpp file. There is no universal logic to header files, it is just a way to design a program, one of.  Different languages may employ different restrictions on header files.

Comment: Okay, I understood you. Thanks.

Comment: I got some time and tried to clear the situation with header files a bit.